# Copy elevation from points to line

Tags: qgis, point, merge, elevation

I have a vector line, but it has no z-dimension.

I have some points along the line, which have the elevation included.

[image]

Can I add the elevation from the points to the line at that specific point?

QGIS 3.4.4

Comment: Have you tried `join attributes by location`? If so, what went wrong?

Comment: Yes - I don't get any of the elevations into my new joined line.

Comment: Did you check whether the point are really sitting on top of the line? What settings did you use? Why didn't you include this into your post?

Comment: Do you want to store the elevation data as an attribute? Or do you want to convert your line to a 3-D line and store the elevation as Z coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

Convert your 2-D line to a 3-D line with the `Set Z values` tool. Define the Z value with this expression, substituting your layer and field names:

```
geomnearest( 'point layer', 'elevation field')
```

(Make sure you have the RefFunctions plugin installed, or you won't have access to the `geomnearest()` function.)

[image]

Be sure to save the output as a permanent layer.